# How can I calculate End date automatically in Php?

Tags: php

How can I calculate End date automatically in Php ?
When I enter current date it will be auto calculate  16moths or 480days.
duration between current and end date 16month and days.

Comment: What does this have to do with `javascript`, `jquery` or `jquery-ui`? Please remove irrelevant tags

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It might be best to take the Tour and to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$Date = "2021-09-27";
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' + 480 days'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this solution:**

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');

$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate. ' + 480 days'));


echo $currentDate;

echo '<br>';

echo $endDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

```
    $time = new DateTime(date('Y:m:d H:i:s'));
$time->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));
 echo $endtime = $time->format('Y:m:d H:i:s');
```

for more info visit: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php